# Enable Excel form navigation by tabbing through

Tags: excel, vba, activex

I have several activeX buttons and combo boxes placed in an excel document.  Right now, to go from one object to another I have to select the next object with my mouse.  I'd like to be able to just hit the tab key to go from one combo box to another.   Does anyone have any ideas on this?

Answer (score 0):

You could code the KeyDown event and look for Tab, then activate whichever control you want. Here's an example where there are three comboboxes on a sheet and tab and <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd> can be used to navigate among them.

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_KeyDown(ByVal KeyCode As MSForms.ReturnInteger, ByVal Shift As Integer)

    If KeyCode = vbKeyTab Then
        NavOle Me.OLEObjects(Me.ComboBox1.Index), Shift
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub ComboBox2_KeyDown(ByVal KeyCode As MSForms.ReturnInteger, ByVal Shift As Integer)

    If KeyCode = vbKeyTab Then
        NavOle Me.OLEObjects(Me.ComboBox2.Index), Shift
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub ComboBox3_KeyDown(ByVal KeyCode As MSForms.ReturnInteger, ByVal Shift As Integer)

    If KeyCode = vbKeyTab Then
        NavOle Me.OLEObjects(Me.ComboBox3.Index), Shift
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub NavOle(ByRef OleActive As OLEObject, Shift As Integer)

    If Shift = 1 Then
        If OleActive.Index = 1 Then
            Me.OLEObjects(Me.OLEObjects.Count).Activate
        Else
            Me.OLEObjects(OleActive.Index - 1).Activate
        End If
    Else
        If OleActive.Index = Me.OLEObjects.Count Then
            Me.OLEObjects(1).Activate
        Else
            Me.OLEObjects(OleActive.Index + 1).Activate
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```

If you don't want to include every OLEObject in the navigation scheme, it gets more complicated.